# How to optimize Excel 2007 cell width for printing?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

I have an Excel spreadsheet with 5 columns.  Two columns have cells which contain very little text (e.g., dates or prices) while three columns have cells which can sometimes contain several rows of (wrapped) text.

I would like to balance the available page width of the spreadsheet between these three columns so as to minimize the spreadsheet's total height and hence the number of pages printed.  Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: There is no automated way to do this and it is time consuming to do it manually, especially if there are many pages.  You run into complications like what fits on each page and whether changes will save a whole page.  Go into page break view, adjust the column widths of the wrapped columns to reallocate space and see what happens to the overall length.  Often, improving one page will make another page worse.  You are likely to find that unless there are just a few rows on the last page, playing around won't save a page.

Comment: You are likely to have more effect by using a narrow font for the wrapped text (like arial narrow).  Look for cells with many wrapped lines, where that cell is the limiting factor and the last line is short, and see if you can reword the text to eliminate the last line.

Comment: Another thing you can try is to set "fit to page(s)". You can do that from Page Setup, or from the Print dialogue (select Custom Scaling). The latter is best, because you can then preview what the pages will look like.